# Using Url.Action with no route values truncates the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, urlhelper

I've got a site that's using making heavy use of AJAX, and in-order to keep things like Urls in a sensible place, I'm outputting the required Urls in a script block on the page, and then using them in a Javascript file later.

An example of this would be:

***In Index.cshtml***

```
<script>
    if (!app.frontoffice)
        app.frontoffice = {};
    if (!app.frontoffice.urls)
        app.frontoffice.urls = {};

    if (!app.frontoffice.urls.index)
        app.frontoffice.urls.index = "@Url.Action("index", "frontoffice", new { area = string.Empty, id = string.Empty })";
</script>
```

***In a JS file somewhere***

```
$(function() {
    $("myButton").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: app.frontoffice.urls.index,
            data: {
                id: 55
            },
            success: ...
            error: ...
        });
    });
});
```

The issue is that the generated Url is created like so - `/frontoffice`, notice it's excluding the `index` action. This is because when it was generated we gave it an empty `id`, so when we come to use it, the Url that gets requested is actually `/frontoffic/55', not`/frontoffice/index/55'..

The `UrlHelper` seems to be culling the action name from url. Is there another method I can use that doesn't remove items from the Url? - I was hoping to get away with a clear, reusable solution as this kind of thing happens all over the site.

Thanks
Kieron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a placeholder for the id.

```
app.frontoffice.urls.index = function (id) {
    return "@Url.Action("index", "frontoffice", new { id = "000" })".replace('000', id);
}
```

Then in your .js file

```
$(function() {
    $("myButton").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: app.frontoffice.urls.index(55),
            success: ...
            error: ...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably needs to be taken care of in your route definitions. You probably still have something like this defined:

`routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});`

For one I would probably remove this or put something that explicitly defines the URL you're generating above the default route definition.